# How to set a property observer on system variable

Tags: ios, property-observer

I have the following variable: `private var screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width`

I was wondering how I could set a property observer on it? Or get the latest version of it when it updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general approach that works for everything.  You can often use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  In this case, you can listen for the [`UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification) notification.